# Concativity of entropy without Jensen's inequality

Tags: analysis, inequality, convex-analysis, entropy, jensen-inequality

In my information theory class I need to prove that entropy is concave (which is usually done with Jensen's inequality). But I want to use only the definition of entropy. And as the result of derivations I get a wrong answer.

Here what I do:

I need to prove that:

$$\lambda {\rm H} \left(p\right)+\left(1-\lambda \right){\rm H} \left(q\right)\le {\rm H} \left(\lambda p+\left(1-\lambda \right)q\right)$$

I use the definitions of entropy (with the summation carried out over $\textit{p}$ or $\textit{q}$, or ($\textit{p}$ and $\textit{q}$)):

$$\lambda {\rm H} \left(p\right)={\rm {\mathbb E}}_{p} \log \frac{1}{p^{\lambda } } ={\rm {\mathbb E}}_{p,q} \log \frac{1}{p^{\lambda }}$$

$$\left(1-\lambda \right){\rm H} \left(q\right)={\rm {\mathbb E}}_{q} \log \frac{1}{q^{\left(1-\lambda \right)} } ={\rm {\mathbb E}}_{p,q} \log \frac{1}{q^{\left(1-\lambda \right)} } $$

$${\rm H} \left(\lambda p+\left(1-\lambda \right)q\right)={\rm {\mathbb E}}_{p,q} \log \frac{1}{\lambda p+\left(1-\lambda \right)q} $$

Then collecting everything and moving to the left-hand side:

$${\rm {\mathbb E}}_{p,q} \log \frac{1}{p^{\lambda } } +{\rm {\mathbb E}}_{p,q} \log \frac{1}{q^{\left(1-\lambda \right)} } ={\rm {\mathbb E}}_{p,q} \log \frac{1}{p^{\lambda } q^{\left(1-\lambda \right)} } $$

$${\rm {\mathbb E}}_{p,q} \log \frac{1}{p^{\lambda } q^{\left(1-\lambda \right)} } -{\rm {\mathbb E}}_{p,q} \log \frac{1}{\lambda p+\left(1-\lambda \right)q} \le 0$$

Using log properties:

$${\rm {\mathbb E}}_{p,q} \log \frac{\lambda p+\left(1-\lambda \right)q}{p^{\lambda } q^{\left(1-\lambda \right)} } \le 0$$

So I have to prove that the ration under log is less than unity (for log to be negative):

$$\frac{\lambda p+\left(1-\lambda \right)q}{p^{\lambda } q^{\left(1-\lambda \right)} } \le 1$$

Finally I get the inequality which is definitely wrong (since AM-GM says me so):

$$\lambda p+\left(1-\lambda \right)q\le p^{\lambda } q^{\left(1-\lambda \right)} $$

So, where I am wrong?

Comment: After "collecting [...] " the equation is wrong. Correctly, it would read  ${\rm {\mathbb E}}_{p,q} \log \frac{1}{p^{\lambda } } {\color{red}{+}}{\rm {\mathbb E}}_{p,q} \log \frac{1}{q^{\left(1-\lambda \right)} } ={\rm {\mathbb E}}_{p,q} \log \frac{1}{p^{\lambda } q^{\left(1-\lambda \right)} }$.

Comment: @Andreas yep, thanks, that was a typo and now it is fixed.

Comment: Can you explain more for the notation $\mathbb{E}_{p, q}$ in $H(\lambda p + (1-\lambda)q) = \mathbb{E}_{p, q}[\log \frac{1}{\lambda p + (1-\lambda)q}]$?
For example, $n=2$. 
LHS equals $(\lambda p_1 + (1-\lambda)q_1)\log \frac{1}{\lambda p_1 + (1-\lambda)q_1}
+ (\lambda p_2 + (1-\lambda)q_2)\log \frac{1}{\lambda p_2 + (1-\lambda)q_2}$.

Answer (score 1):

This is just answering what went wrong (not using your chain of ideas for  indeed proving concavity of entropy).

You have abandoned the expectation probabilities. Correctly,
 ${\rm {\mathbb E}}_{p} F(p) = \sum_{x_i} p(x_i) F(p(x_i))$.

1) As a first example, let $\lambda = \frac12$, $p=1$, $q=0^+$. Then, applying your ideas (without expectation probabilities) to the very first line, you get

$$
\lambda {\rm H} \left(p\right)+\left(1-\lambda \right){\rm H} \left(q\right)\le {\rm H} \left(\lambda p+\left(1-\lambda \right)q\right) \\
\leftrightarrow\\
\frac12 \log \frac{1}{1} + \frac12 \log \frac{1}{0^+}\le \log \frac{1}{\frac12 \cdot 1 + \frac12 \cdot 0 } = \log 2
$$
which is of course wrong.  The correct treatment, including the expectation probabilities, is 
$$
\frac12 \cdot 1 \cdot \log \frac{1}{1} + \frac12\cdot  0^+ \cdot \log \frac{1}{0^+}\le  \frac12\log 2
$$
and this is correct, since $0^+ \cdot \log \frac{1}{0^+} \to 0^+ $.

2) In a general setting which you want to pursue, putting the expectation probabilities in, you have (where for short, ${\rm {\mathbb E}} f(p) = \sum_{x_i} f(p(x_i))$ is used),
$$
{\rm {\mathbb E}}_{p,q} \log \frac{1}{p^{\lambda } } +{\rm {\mathbb E}}_{p,q} \log \frac{1}{q^{\left(1-\lambda \right)} } = {\rm {\mathbb E}}\left[ p \log \frac{1}{p^{\lambda } } + q \log \frac{1}{q^{\left(1-\lambda \right)} }\right]
$$
and, somewhat more involved,
$$
{\rm {\mathbb E}}_{p,q} \log \frac{1}{\lambda p+\left(1-\lambda \right)q}={\rm {\mathbb E}}\left[({\lambda p+\left(1-\lambda \right)q})\log \frac{1}{\lambda p+\left(1-\lambda \right)q}\right]
$$
which leaves you to show
$$
 p \log \frac{1}{p^{\lambda } } + q \log \frac{1}{q^{\left(1-\lambda \right)} }\le ({\lambda p+\left(1-\lambda \right)q})\log \frac{1}{\lambda p+\left(1-\lambda \right)q}
$$
Continuing as you have laid it out would result in having to show 
$$
  \frac{({\lambda p+\left(1-\lambda \right)q})^{({\lambda p+\left(1-\lambda \right)q})}}{p^{\lambda p} \cdot q^{\left(1-\lambda \right) q}} \le 1
$$
but I do not think this will lead us somewhere.

3) As a third piece of explanation which shows the effects of the above error versus the correct treatment, just notice that $\log (1/x)$ is convex whereas $x \log (1/x)$ is concave ... this says it all.